# PHP file size more than

Tags: php, file, size

```
<?php
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '70M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '70M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 6000);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300000);


$f = 'path';

$obj = new COM ( 'scripting.filesystemobject' );

if ( is_object ( $obj ) )
{
$ref = $obj->getfolder ( $f );

//echo 'Directory: ' . $f . ' => Size: ' . $ref->size;

$obj = null;
}
else
{
//echo 'can not create object';
}

if ( $ref->size < 32212254720){


 if (($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
  || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "audio/wav")
  || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg")
   && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] >= 26214400)
 && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"]<= 70000000)
 )
   {

things done

else
   {
echo error
}
echo error space if full
}
```

the problem is that `($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] >= 26214400)` dont work, i can upload files less than 25 mb still?! is that normal? i upload file that is 800bytes and it works  any idea how to make it work? or if there is another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if (($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
  || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "audio/wav")
  || ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg")
   && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] >= 26214400)
 && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"]<= 70000000)
 )
```

is wrong, hard to maintain and unreliable.

First of all you are mixing `||` and `&&` without grouping `||` in one parenthesis - this is your main problem here. Easily fixed by adding one more set of parenthesis:

```
if (
    (
     ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")||($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "audio/wav")||($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg")
    )  
    && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] >= 26214400)
    && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"]<= 70000000)
)
```

But this is unreadable, so let's just define an array of allowed values and check against it:

```
$allowed = array("audio/mp3", "audio/wav", "audio/mpeg");
if (
   in_array($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"], $allowed)
   && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] >= 26214400)
   && ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"]<= 70000000)
)
```

Last thing - `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"]` can be changed/malformed/spoofed, so it's not something to trust. Use server side solutions to determine filetype by content.

Comment: i fixed it just before reading your post but no doubt learnt things that i missed in your post like $_FILES is not to be trusted but i would like to show me how to do it with server sice to check content itself even in a simple way :) thanks alot